# jQuery Cycle with defined pager links

Tags: jquery, edit, pager, definitions

I built a player using cycle that cycles through various promos but I want to define the specific descriptive pager links for each page (other than 1,2,3, etc.) I know this should be possible but cannot figure out how... Even when I have added elements in the pager div they show up but the numbers that are auto generated are what controls the player. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#promoPlayer').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed: 600,
    timeout: 6000,
    delay: 1000,
    pager:'#pager'
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you will want to use the callback function `pagerAnchorBuilder` for generating the Pager links.

You can return any html string from the function, and it receives the current slide as the first parameter. From there, you can create your own structure.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#promoPlayer').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed: 600,
    timeout: 6000,
    delay: 1000,
    pager:'#pager',

    // callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
    return '<li><a href="#">my custom link #'+ idx +'</a></li>'; 
} 
  });
})
```

A live exampe can be seen at http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html